# Homemade pop tarts coming out too dry / crumbly

Tags: baking

So I just recently attempted to make my own pop tarts using the recipe found here: http://rampantcuisine.com/cuisine/homemade-pop-tarts/

But the tarts came out rather dry and crumbly like shortbread, as opposed to the "flaky" that you see in the pictures. I'm not quite sure what went wrong here, but I'm guessing that it had something to do with the amount of liquid I used. Any ideas on what might have caused it or how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your pastry dough was overworked, so that the butter was too incorporated.

To get the flakiness you desire, when the dough is rolled flat, there should be layers of whole butter sandwiching floury layers.

If the butter is worked too far into the dough, instead you will get a sandy or crumbly texture.

Comment: That makes sense, I did work it quite a bit when I was trying to roll it out (I don't have a rolling pin...). I'll try it again and see if less working makes a difference.

Comment: This would be a very difficult recipe to try without a rolling pin, as rolling the dough out thinly is key to its success.  A clean wine bottle with the label removed might do in a pinch.

Comment: A rolling pin would be a good investment in the future, and not costly. I've seen a baseball bat used in a pinch, but my favorite rolling pin substitute is a clean length of metal pipe straight out of the fridge. The cold metal helps to keep the pastry cool, which is a good thing, and it can be used to fight off intruders as well!

Comment: I've heard that a tall, round glass would work just as well, has anyone tried it?

Comment: Never tried a glass, but I have used the wine bottle.  They are far stronger than drinking glasses.